# X86 assembly - Handling array-type parameters

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I am currently writing a simple C compiler, that takes a .c file as input and generates assembly code (X86, AT&T syntax). I am having a hard time passing array-type parameters and generating the correct assembly code for it. Here's my input:

```
int getIndexOne(int tab[]){
  return tab[1];
}

int main_test(void){
  int t[3];
  t[0] = 0;
  t[1] = 1;
  t[2] = 2;
  return getIndexOne(t);
}
```

A fairly simple test. Here is my output:

```
getIndexOne:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -24(%ebp)
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    -24(%ebp, %eax, 8), %eax    #trouble over here
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size getIndexOne, .-getIndexOne


falsemain:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $120, %esp
    movl    $2, -32(%ebp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $0, -24(%ebp, %eax, 8)
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $1, -24(%ebp, %eax, 8)
    movl    $2, %eax
    movl    $2, -24(%ebp, %eax, 8)
    leal    -24(%ebp, %eax, 8), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    getIndexOne
    addl    $120, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size main_test, .-main_test
```

I'm unable to access the content of the passed address (leal instruction). Any help would be much appreciated.
PS: Don't worry about the size of my ints, they are set to 8 instead of 4 bytes for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems, the first being when you setup the stack for the call to `getIndexOne`:

```
movl    $2, %eax
movl    $2, -24(%ebp, %eax, 8)
leal    -24(%ebp, %eax, 8), %eax   ##<== EAX still holds value of 2!
movl    %eax, %edi                 ##<== wrong address for start of array
```

You're not clearing the contents of the `EAX` register after the `MOV` command, therefore the address that you're putting into the `EDI` register for the function call is not pointing to the start of the array, but last element of the array (i.e., the second index which has an element value of `2`).

The second problem comes here in your `getIndexOne` function:

```
movl    %edi, -24(%ebp)
movl    $1, %eax
movl    -24(%ebp, %eax, 8), %eax
```

You've stored the address on the stack.  That's fine, but it also means when you retreive the value from the stack, that you're getting a pointer back which must then be dereferenced *a second time*.  What you're doing right now is you're just reading back a value offset from the frame-pointer on the stack ... that's not the value in the array since you're not dereferencing the pointer that you stored on the stack.  In other words you should change it to the following if you must store the pointer on the stack (I think this isn't the most efficient way since the value is already in `EDI`, but whatever):

```
movl    %edi, -24(%ebp)           ##<== store pointer to the array on the stack
movl    $1, %eax
movl    -24(%ebp), %ecx           ##<== get the pointer back from the stack
movl    (%ecx, %eax, 8), %eax     ##<== dereference the pointer
```

As a side note, while I'm not sure how your compiler works, I do think it's a little scary that you are using the value that you are loading into the array elements to also index into the array ... if the values being loaded don't match the array index, that's going to create quite a bit of havok ... I'm guessing this is some type of optimization you're attempting to-do when the two values match?

Comment: I have tried two different ways:
 
1) load 0 in EAX before the leal instruction.
2) Replace the leal instruction with: leal -24(%ebp).
 
In both situations, I get a wrong result.
What other method would you suggest in this scenario?

Comment: This seems to solve the issue. I'll do some further testing then I'll get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Okay great, all the tests cleared, thank you for your help!
As for your question about how my compiler works:
When handling arrays, lets say arr[exp], I first evaluate exp and load it in EAX, and then extract the value (like in the code above). As for issues like out-of-bound-index, I already verify that at an earlier stage (Java-side).
There you go, and thanks for your help!